# using javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I'm not understanding what happens to the `StreamResult` instance.  I see that the `Transformer` object receives `source` and `streamResult`:

```
    transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

this transforms `source` into `streamResult`?  It seems odd that there's nothing returned from this [operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform(javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result)) yet `streamResult` now has, for lack of a better word, data.  Is it `xml` data?

```
package helloWorldSaxon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

public class App {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    private final Properties properties = new Properties();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, TransformerConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        LOG.fine("starting..");
        new App().identyTransformOnURL();
    }

    private void identyTransformOnURL() throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, IOException, SAXException {
        properties.loadFromXML(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/saxon.xml"));
        String url = properties.getProperty("url");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser");
        Source source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, new InputSource(url));

        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, streamResult);

        String stringResult = writer.toString();
        LOG.info(stringResult);
    }

}
```

I don't understand the JavaDoc on this method:

```
Transform the XML Source to a Result.
```

Wouldn't it be more intuitive to **return** a result?

Comment: I suggest we concentrate on getting your code to work, and try to avoid discussions of whether JAXP could have been better designed. Yes it could, but that's not going to help you move forward. (And it's out of scope for StackOverflow anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line in question takes in an XML source and another object (i.e. `Result`) where the results of the transformation can be written. In essence, the second argument is a bucket you provide that allows the `transform` method to place its results. Once the method call is over, you retrieve your bucket and take the results out of it.

In your particular case:

```
transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

The `streamResult` object is a streamed writer that encapsulates a `StringWriter`. This `streamResult` object is then passed to the `transform` method, which writes its results to the `StreamResult`, which in turn writes the results to the `StringWriter`. You can then call the `toString` method on the `StringWriter` to view the stringified results of the transformation.

To answer your second question: Some methods do not return their results as a matter of efficiency and flexibility. For example, suppose a very large number of transformations are performed. If the results were returned, a new object would need to be created for each one of these transformations. In the case where a result object is passed in (called an *out parameter*), the same result object can be reused over and over. Secondly, returning the result removes some flexibility, as it does not allow the user to specify *how* the results should be written. In your case, you were able to pass in a `StringWriter` wrapped inside a `StreamResult`, but you just as easily could have passed in any object that implements the `Result` interface.

There are some alternatives to this type of out parameter using lambda expressions and functional programming, but at the time XML transformation interface was written, out parameters were a common practice (and in some cases, still are).

Comment: leaving open for a bit, but I think you got it in one.  I appreciate the terminology and context.  Makes more sense.

Comment: I guess part of the original motivation might have been that the StreamResult can pipe data into an HTTP response which potentially allows the browser to start displaying results before the transformation has completed.

Comment: @MichaelKay True, that would be a good use case. Streams and functional interfaces could replace this with a return value that can be chained (with JDK 8+), but until that point, there wasn't many easy ways to do that.